Will Azure Notification Hubs support the upcoming APNs Certification Authority change in 2025?
Apple has announced a change in the Certification Authority (CA) for APNs. Starting January 20, 2025 (sandbox) and February 24, 2025 (production), Apple will use the USERTrust RSA Certification Authority to sign their APNs server certificates.
I use Azure Notification Hubs to send push notifications to iOS devices. Since Azure manages the communication with APNs, I want to know:
Will Azure Notification Hubs update their Trust Store to include the new USERTrust RSA Certification Authority certificate?
If anyone has information or guidance on this, I would appreciate it.
Thank you!
P.S. I already saw relevant question regarding firebase but nothing about azure even in their blog.

I apologize for the English, I used Google Translate to prepare this answer. Let's go:
I had the same question and asked Microsoft Learn about it and the answer I got was the following in this link;
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/answers/questions/2127433/a-autoridade-certificadora-(ca)-para-apple-push-no
Apparently, we Azure Notification Hubs users do not need to take any action regarding this, but if you have more information it would be interesting.
